# My app is crashing on iOS 7.0.2

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

My development environment is iPad3, iOS7 and Xcode5. My app works fine in earlier version (Xcode 4.6.3 and iOS5.1 and 6)

The issue I am facing is sporadic and does not always occur.

Here is the exception,

```
-[__NSCFType count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14dbc7a0
Oct 20 17:18:43 akilas-iPad DogFight[4437] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14dbc7a0'
```

Here is the code piece which seems to be causing the issue:

```
-(CGSize ) controlSize:(UILabel *)controlName andText:(NSString *) text maxWidth:(int)width{

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(width,CGFLOAT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:controlName.font
                            constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                lineBreakMode:controlName.lineBreakMode]; // this fails 
return expectedLabelSize;}
```

This does not always fail, only sometimes though quite frequently sometimes code works fine. I am clueless as this seems to work fine on iOS5 & 6.

Any pointers?

Comment: The error is that you are sending a -count method to a string, count is used with collection object. So its something that is expecting a collection but it founds a string.

Answer (score 3):

1) now with 64 bit don't use CGFLOAT_MAX - just use some large number like 10,000.

2) did you really need the new device? Does it crash in the simulator too or just on an actual device?

3) add an exception breakpoint to your project, and when your app crashes you can find out where an why it crashed, and what that object us.

Comment: David, could you elaborate on the use of CGFLOAT_MAX please. Why shouldn't it be used now? (Genuine question) Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister, CGFloats are 64 bits on 64 bits systems. Since dimensions inside iOS (and OSX) are on the orders of thousands, its quite possible that Apple does internal conversion to integral types. While this may not be the issue here, I would offer that using CGFLOAT_MAX in this code. A more common usage would be setting a CGFloat variable to this at the start of a loop, where you are trying to find a minimum.